# Joining lines in a text file

Tags: shell, scripting

Need some help with developing a script to join lines in a text file, ie

```
Blah
\Blah Blah\Bhal
1

Blah2
\Blah Blah\Blah2
600
```

to:

```
Blah:\Blah Blah\Bhal:1
Blah2:\Blah Blah\Blah2:2
```

Output was generated via a DOS batch file, but I can also do the parsing in BASH if it will be any easier.

Comment: I don't see any pattern here... Where should the colons be placed and why?

Comment: There is a pattern, but you have to look hard. Admittedly, the OP could have provided a better example.

Answer (score 4):

The most elegant option in my opinion is to use paste

To join 2 lines

```
paste -sd'::\n'
```

To join 3 lines

```
paste -sd':::\n'
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tr` to change the newlines (`\n`) for something else:

```
tr "\\n" ":" < myfile
```

This would replace every new line for a `:`.

Keep in mind that if you have:

```
foo

bar
```

The result will be `foo::bar` (since you have two newlines). Change accordingly.

Comment: @IRO-bot: That's how I roll! Also, <3 your username :)